# Удалить "#" из строки

Tags: python, строки, for

В общем у меня есть код, и я хочу убрать "#".Но когда я запускаю код он выводит только первый символ строки.

```
def remove_url_anchour(url):
    for i in url:
        return ''.join(list(i.split('#')))      
    
print(remove_url_anchour("www.codewars.com#about")) #выводит просто w
```

Comment: потому что `"www.codewars.com#about"` - это строка, а не список. Цикл `for` просто возвращает первый символ

Comment: либо передавать параметр так `["www.codewars.com#about"]`, либо избавляться от цикла. Результат каким должен быть?

Comment: а для чего убирать этот символ ? фигня ведь получится www.codewars.comabout

Comment: @Интик Да наверняка автор хочет просто адрес сайта получить, убрав и # и всё что после него

Answer (score 3):

1. Смысла от конструкции `list(i.split('#'))` абсолютно нет, т.к. `.split` возвращает список.
2. Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать, то такой код должен подойти (убирает все, что после символа "#", включая его):

```
def remove_url_anchour(url):
    '''Убирает все, что после символа "#", включая его.'''
    return url.split('#')[0]
    
url = 'www.codewars.com#about'
r_url = remove_url_anchour(url)
print(r_url) # 'www.codewars.com'
```

3. Или такой код (убирает символ "#"):

```
def remove_url_anchour(url):
    '''Убирает символ "#".'''
    return url.replace('#', '')

url = 'www.codewars.com#about'
r_url = remove_url_anchour(url)
print(r_url) # 'www.codewars.comabout'
```